# List comprehensions tip

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Is there a more elegant way to write this?:

```
q = []
for line in lines:
    date = line.split(",", 1)
    q.append(date[0])
```

I´m trying to understand list comprehensions.

Any help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
q = [line.split(",", 1)[0] for line in lines]
```